# How to keep block elements inline and also correctly centered?

Tags: html, css

Trying to have 3 divs on one line, each with an image that is centered within it's allocated third of the page. They all seem to be a bit too far to the left.
Also, how do I center them vertically within the div?

[image: current results]
current results

Here's the code.

HTML

```
<div class="block">
        <div class="left">
            <img class="swork" src="100.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
            <img class="swork" src="010.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <img class="swork" src="001.jpg"/>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.swork {
max-width: 300px;
max-height: 500px;
}

.block {
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
}

.left {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
}

.center {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%
}

.right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
}
```

Comment: *They all seem to be a bit too far to the left.* So I am in doubt whether you want it aligned vertically or horizontally?

Comment: Well, both, as the question states, though not as clearly as it could've.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: middle` and `text-align: center` to the styles for each child div.

Comment: Thank you. That solves the second part of my problem, but not the first.

Comment: Try `text-align: center` too

Answer (score 1):

You just need this:

```
.block {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L0s29jr5/)

Comment: For flexbox solution:+1  Unfortunately <=IE10 browsers do not support that.

Answer (score 0):

try this for css:

```
<STYLE>
.swork {
max-width: 300px;
max-height: 500px;
}

.block {
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    align-content:center;
}

.left {
    display: inline-table;
    width: 33%;
    align-content:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.center {
    display: inline-table;
    width: 33%;
    align-content:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.right {
    display: inline-table;
    width: 33%;
    align-content:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
</STYLE>
```

And set your block div to align="center".

Answer (score 0):

Try this block class css..

```
.block {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```